# AWS Lightsail Bitnami LAMP - Installing 2nd Wordpress Module not working

Tags: mysql, wordpress, amazon-web-services, lamp, bitnami

I have a LAMP stack on my AWS Lightsail server with one wordpress application currently. I am trying to load another wordpress intall, `wordpresskva`, on my server (not using multisite for personal reasons). So I ran the bitnami installer with --wordpress_instance_name wordpresskva. But it fails when I get to:

```
Create Admin account

Please enter the MySQL password for "root" for the existing Bitnami installation

Password :
```

I put in the application password (`bitnami_application_password` in the ~ directory) but it then says:

```
Warning: The installer was not able to connect to the MySQL server. Please make 
sure MySQL is running and introduce a valid password to connect to the MySQL 
server.
Press [Enter] to continue:
```

This is strange, since when I enter the same password here:

```
$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
```

It lets me get into the mysql server. I checked the status of the server and everything seems fine, so I am really confused as to what is wrong with the password/setup I am using.

Could you please help me troubleshoot this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you're following the guide below:

https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/apps/wordpress/#how-to-install-several-wordpress-modules-on-the-same-stack

And I also guess you're using the WordPress module installer below:

https://downloads.bitnami.com/files/stacks/wordpress/4.9.4-2/bitnami-wordpress-4.9.4-2-module-linux-x64-installer.run

I just launched a new LAMP Server on Lightsail and run the commands:

```
wget https://downloads.bitnami.com/files/stacks/wordpress/4.9.4-2/bitnami-wordpress-4.9.4-2-module-linux-x64-installer.run
chmod +X bitnami-wordpress-4.9.4-2-module-linux-x64-installer.run
sudo ./bitnami-wordpress-4.9.4-2-module-linux-x64-installer.run
```

And I chose **/opt/bitnami** as installation directory:

```
Please choose a folder that contains an installation of Bitnami.

Select a folder []: /opt/bitnami/
```

Then I use the use the password obtained from **bitnami_application_password** when prompted for the MySQL password:

Please enter the MySQL password for "root" for the existing Bitnami installation

```
Password :

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
WordPress

Please configure WordPress installation
```

As you can check everything worked as expected. Please repeat the process and ensure you type the password correctly (with no spaces), it should work.

Comment: I'm not really sure what happened, but the steps do not work for me. Can you try creating two wordpress instances, if that is what generates the problem?

Comment: Yes, I tried to add several WordPress instances and I successfully have several blogs on top of the same stack. Did you modify MySQL somehow (credentials, socket, etc.)?

Comment: No, I haven't. I made a new lightsail instance and I was able to do it from a clean install. I still have no idea what the problem was though.

Comment: @Juan how many blogs were you able to install? I setup a multisite version with 3 blogs in 2017 and want to add a 4th. Forgot why I switched to multisite then and recall 3 was a limit then. Also Neil - why not multisite if I may ask? If it's not personal-personal that is...

Comment: when I try to set the folder /opt/bitnami I get "the direcotry is not writable by the current user"

Comment: https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/apps/wordpress/#how-to-install-several-wordpress-modules-on-the-same-stack this link is not working for me..
can you guide me how to install another Wordpress in same instance ?